# Which event is triggered for auto populated Input Field?

Tags: reactjs

I have an input field whose value is auto populated based on another Input feild. How to set that? Which event is used for auto populate?

My Input Field looks like this:

```
<Input
 name="price"
ref="price"
initValue={this.state.projectPrice}
value={this.state.projectPrice}
rules={[
Rules.minValue(3,"message---")
]}
```

If I display in `<p>{this.state.ProjectPrice}</p>` I am getting the values,but I am unable to bind that with the Input Field. The input field should be auto-populated on change of another function.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,

If I am getting it right as you described, I have made this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-mgj2q?fontsize=14).

What it does is read the changes from the first input, saves it's value in the state, and also populate a value for the second input, which is controlled by a value that depends on the changes from the first input and the only way to modify that value is by setting the value for the first input..

Don't hesitate if more clarifications are required.

Comment: Hi..I tried this. it is not working for me. My input field looks like this:

Comment: can you include the code as an edit to your question? it'll be better for us to solve the problem if we see code.